# Not able to add unique rows using sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on Android 2.3 Simulator.

I have some 5 unique categories...

I need to add these categories in my table....

I added it using **primary key** like this

> Create table if not exists test (category integer primary key, value text) ;

But if i execute this query twice

> insert into test(category, value) values(1,"0");

Then it is adding this twice

Even if i use **unique** like this

> Create table if not exists test (category integer unique, value text) ;

Then also it is adding the row twice...

How to make a row unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont add record manually ie for primary key, you can assign *primary key as auto increment*, let system will add record.

Comment: That's a Nice Approach... But can you tell me which one will be efficient... 1)unique 2)primary Key 3) primary key with auto increment ?

Comment: primary key with auto increment will be better. (category primary key autoincrement, valu....)